# fprintf is not declared in this scope

Tags: compiler-errors, codeblocks

I'm trying to run this code in code blocks 12.11 and keep getting this error:fprintf is not declared in this scope

```
# include <GL/glew.h>
# include <GL/freeglut.h>


using namespace std;

//any time the window is resized, this function is called. It set up to the
// "glutReshapeFunc" in Maine.
void changeViewport(int w, int h) {
   glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

//Here is the function that gets called each time the window needs to be redrawn.
//It is the "paint" method for our program, and it is set up from the glutDisplayFunc in         main.
void render() {
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
//Initialize GLUT
glutInit(&argc, argv);

//Set up some memory buffers for our display
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
//set the window size
glutInitWindowSize(900, 600);
//Create the window with the title "Hello, GL"
glutCreateWindow("Hello, GL");
//Bind the two functions (above) to respond when necessary
glutReshapeFunc(changeViewport);
glutDisplayFunc(render);

//Very important! This initializes the entry points in the OpenGL driver so we can
//call functions in the API.
GLenum err = glewInit();
if (GLEW_OK != err) {
    fprintf(stderr, "GLEW error");
    return 1;
}

//Start up a loop that runs in the background (you never see it).
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

I am unsure as to what to do. If anybody has any ideas please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Put

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

at the top of your file. That's where printf and its variants live.